# Valid HTML Vs. Viewable HTML

Tags: discussion, scope

If a user can view the HTML the way they need to on IE (hypothetically), but the HTML isn't valid, is it still On-Topic?

How have you decided this in past?  Should we continue to use the same set of specifications to define off-topic HTML?

HTML that is viewable on IE, but not valid, may not display correctly on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, etc.

So, is valid or viewable the standard of measure for HTML?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I say, from the point of view of someone who writes HTML/CSS, yes it is On-Topic, if it works *as the OP intended*, or put differently, *as far as they know*.

HTML being a mark-up language, rather than programming, is a lot more lenient and browsers often are very forgiving to "invalid" HTML. If it were not the case, I'd wager **many** popular websites would be out of business. Not all HTML coders know about validators, XHTML compatible self-closed tags, CSS styles, meta-tags, etc.

So, in short, if it works in the intended browser, to me it works as the OP is expecting, so "viewable" I feel would be the most reasonable measuring stick.

Comment: I would agree with this assessment. *Works* is from the perspective of the question-asker.

Comment: if this is the case then --> http://stackoverflow.com/q/28349961/1214743 would be a good fit for migration, other than it lacks description, right?

Comment: it is not off-topic on SO actually, so not a good fit for migration.

Comment: I feel that the question *is* off-topic on SO since it is asking about best practices.  However, the question should have been closed as a duplicate of one of the many "div inside span" questions that already exist.

Comment: How can you close something as a duplicate of a question on site X if it's off-topic for site X?